# How to properly upload a file using GLPI

Tags: laravel, glpi

I am using this GLPI API and I am trying to upload a file.

Here's what I am doing in my code:

```
public static function uploadDocument(TicketRequest $request)
{
    $client = new static();

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $uploadManifest = [
            "input" => [
                "name" => $request['document_title'],
                "_filename" => [$file_name],
            ],
        ];

        $result = $client->upload("Document", [
            'uploadManifest' => json_encode($uploadManifest),
            'filename[0]' => '@' . $file->getPathname(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

But I always get the error `ERROR_UPLOAD_FILE_TOO_BIG_POST_MAX_SIZE`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `ERROR_UPLOAD_FILE_TOO_BIG_POST_MAX_SIZE` because the file you're trying to upload is larger than the limit configured on your server.

It won't happen if you reduce the size of the file you're uploading.

You need to increase the upload limit on your server. You can do this by following [these instructions](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-file-upload-size-in-php/) if you're using Apache.

Comment: The size of the file that I am uploading is just 200kb. But still, the error still popping out.

Comment: Try increasing the POST limits on your server